# Pokemon Go Supported Devices

Tags: pokemon-go, system-requirements

I have a Verizon Ellipsis 8 tablet, and I was wondering: should I be able to run Pokemon Go on it?

Each time I try to open up the app, it loads about 3/4 of the way and then it crashes. I have the newest software downloaded for it and I have tried a bunch of other things.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the details for that particular tablet, but does it meet the requirements listed on the [supported devices](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices) page?

Comment: I saw that it seems that it meets the required specs. So I don't know if it is something else or not.

Comment: The Ellipsis 7 uses an Intel chip. It doesn't work. Not sure, but not surprised if the 8 does as well.

Answer (score 4):

In July 2019 and October 2020, Niantic updated their minimum supported devices and operating systems, dropping support for older Android and iOS versions and devices.

Specifically, Niantic has ceased support for:

#### Android

- **Android v4 (KitKat)** - [Twitter Announcement](https://twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1140710740443193344), [Support Article](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=account-and-sign-in&f=discontinued-support-for-android-4-kitkat&p=web)
- **Android v5 (Lollipop)** - [Support Article](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=all&s=troubleshooting&f=discontinued-support-for-android-5-ios-10-11-and-iphone-5s-6)

#### iOS

- **iOS 9** - [Support Article](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=account-and-sign-in&f=discontinued-support-for-ios-9&p=web)
- **iOS 10 & 11** - [Support Article](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=all&s=troubleshooting&f=discontinued-support-for-android-5-ios-10-11-and-iphone-5s-6)
- **iPhone 5s & 6** - [Support Article](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=all&s=troubleshooting&f=discontinued-support-for-android-5-ios-10-11-and-iphone-5s-6)
- **Apple Watch** - [Support Article](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=account-and-sign-in&f=discontinued-support-for-apple-watch&p=web)

As of writing, the currently supported technical specifications are below. (See Niantic's [Supported Devices](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=troubleshooting&f=supported-devices) Page for the latest):

#### Android

- Android 6 or above
- Preferred resolution of 720 x 1280 pixels (not optimized for tablet)
- Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
- GPS and Location Services
- Rooted devices are not supported

#### iOS

- iPhone 6s or above
- iOS 12 or above
- Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
- GPS and Location Services
- Jailbroken devices are not supported

---

#### What does this mean for your device?

While Pokemon Go now [supports Intel-based processors](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3102652/pokemon-go-now-a-go-on-android-smartphones-with-intel-chips.html), your Verizon Ellipsis 8 is *no longer supported* - the highest available Android OS that your phone supports is 5.1. You will need to get a newer device if you wish to continue to play Pokemon Go.