# Will a Flare J1 Cherry mobile work for Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I downloaded Pokemon Go on Google Playstore before they remove it! And its working and loading after logging in, but when it to 3\4 it crashes and returns me to my home screen. Why does it do this? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Please check your device against the [system specifications for Pokemon Go](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273335/pokemon-go-supported-devices)

Comment: If you can download it from the Play Store the phone will be capable of running Pokémon Go.
It looks like a technical issue, though. Have you tried to reinstall the app?

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be that your device does not meet the [technical specifications](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/How_to_get_the_game#Supported_Devices). You should check the specs of your phone against the required specs.

If this all matches up then you can try to re-install it from an official source. If you've downloaded the APK from a 'dodgy' location then this could explain as well why it doesn't work.

The truth is that it's very difficult to say why it's not working with limited information available.